# Is it possible to create a new network on a LAN with another router?

Tags: networking, router, vlan, subnet

I have a main router (Zyxel XMG3927-B50A) in my house that is a gateway on 192.168.1.1 connected to the WAN and I have another router (DrayTek Vigor2830n) that is connected to the main router. Is it possible to make the second router have a 192.168.0.1 IP and communicate with the main router?

I was hoping for the devices on the second router to have 192.168.0.x IPs to make it easer to manage them whilst still being able to communicate with the WAN

When I look online it recommends that I use VLAN. Ive tried it but it hasn't worked (it might be that ive set it up incorrectly).

Please could anyone provide me some advice on this?
Thank you.

Comment: The 2830n will need 2 ips, 1 on the WAN side which will need to be 192.168.1.x and 1 on the LAN side which can be 192.168.0.x. Set the default gateway on the wan side to be 192.168.1.1

Comment: @Drifter104 Ive given the router two IPs and can connect to them. The only problem is that I can't access the wide area network